# format decimal number using ToString

Tags: c#

If I got decimal number like 14.50 and I want to be represented like `decimal 10.2`

```
0000000014.50
```

how can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: you can do this but the data type will be converted into string. why do you actually do this?

Comment: yes, I'm aware of that, it should be converted into string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx):

```
var value = 14.50m;

string valueString = value.ToString("0000000000.00");
```

`0` is a placeholder: *Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an issue with the data type being converted to string then you could use Padding in c#.

Refer the link below :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.100).aspx